# Multi Tenant System MIgration from MYSQL to POSTGRES

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, multi-tenant, postgresql-9.3

My application's DB is in MYSQL and I m trying to implement Multi-tenant system using Apartment Gem. The requirement of the gem is that you must have a POSTGRES Db. So how I can migrate my existing MYSQL Db to POSTGRES.

Comment: Apartment does not require you must use Postgres! it supports sqlite, mysql and postgres just fine

Comment: Backup everything before you start. I would use tools to do the work. MySQL Workbench - export data functions, and PG Admin III -- import data functions. Read about creating a pg database using the schema.rb  - Create the new Postgres database with a rake db:create - then import the MySQL data from your dump using PG Admin III. It may or may not go smoothly the first time. I'm not putting this as an answer because this is advice of a tool-based way to do the conversion. Using this you can validate results of each step instead of mashing everything together at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently done this in one of my projects. Migrating data from `mysql` to `pg` is bit tricky. For this you would have to carefully get all the `mysql db` records from all `rails models`, hashify the data and then import it in `pg`. Lets divide the whole procedure in steps which are:

1- Make a connection to `mysql db`

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( :adapter => "mysql", :host => "host", :username => "username", :password => "password", :database => "db_name" )
```

2- Get `mysql` rows from all models and hashify

```
["Model1", "Model2", "Model3", "Model4", "Model5"].each do |modal|
    eval("@#{modal.downcase} = #{modal}.all.collect{ |p| p.to_dh }")    
end
```

3- Now make connection to your current db which is `pg`

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:development)
```

4- Switch to new `tenant` that you want to `export` data to

```
Apartment::Tenant.switch!('tenant_name')
```

5- Create records in `rails models` that are migrated in `pg` from hashified `mysql` data

```
["Model1", "Model2", "Model3", "Model4", "Model5"].each do |modal|
    eval("@#{modal.downcase}.each{ |p| #{modal}.create(p[:attributes], :without_protection => true) rescue p[:id]}")
end
```

6- Now you will need to reset the ID's so records can be created by rails from preceding record and not from 1.

```
["Model1", "Model2", "Model3", "Model4", "Model5"].each do |modal|
     ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(eval("#{modal}.table_name"))
end
```

There you go. Now you have all of your `mysql` data migrated into your `pg` `database`.